# How to get the last 8 characters in a string by using regex

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

I want to get the last 8 characters of a string by using regex. Here are some examples:

```
psG8FKzmVz -> G8FKzmVz
es5xd2bC47 -> 5xd2bC47
ese2SapMT3 -> e2SapMT3
```

Please help on this.

Comment: Why has it to be regex? It's quite a simple string operation.

Comment: i can get it by substr as well, but for large expressions i found out regexp is gud, so i tried it and failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use regex for something like this, but this should work:

```
(.{0,8})$
```

Comment: Thx Blender, it's working. but i did't understand how it is working, i am thinking like 0,8 means first 8 letters. or because of $ it's treating backward ?

Comment: @Dileep: `$` is the end of the string. `.{0,8}` matches at most 8 characters, so you get the last 8 characters of the string.

Comment: in case if i want last 5 characters, i can use .{0,5} ? and at the same time if i want beginning of the letters how can i?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you want to count from the beginning just leave the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions, it seems a very simple string operation. Use substr

If it is complex string extraction you can opt for regex